# Is it possible to translate or convert a VBS script to BAT?

Tags: windows, batch-file, conversion, vbscript, translation

I have a visual basic script I found years ago, I would like to know if it can be entirely or at least roughly translated into batch format. The goal is to convert the script to batch format, so that I can use [BAT to EXE](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) to convert the resulting batch file into an executable binary. The script hides or shows hidden files, here's the scripts contents:

```
Hidden = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden"
SSHidden = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ShowSuperHidden"
Set Command1 = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set command2 = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Check = Command1.RegRead(Hidden)
If Check = 2 Then
Command1.RegWrite Hidden, 1, "REG_DWORD"
Command1.RegWrite SSHidden, 1, "REG_DWORD"
Else
Command1.RegWrite Hidden, 2, "REG_DWORD"
Command1.RegWrite SSHidden, 0, "REG_DWORD"
End If
Command1.SendKeys "{F5}"
WScript.sleep 1000
```

I'm not a professional programmer, but I have seen VBS translated to batch before, I just don't know all of the ins-and-outs of how to do so. I could make two batch scripts, one to hide, one to show, but the VBS script does both. I would like to retain this singularity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the registry use Batch code, but why would you if the VB script works?

Comment: Because I am going to use BAT to EXE converter, I just prefer to convert my utility scripts into exe binary format. I like to add things like icons and version information as well, so I suppose it's more for athletics.

Comment: Export a registry key, using regedit, to see how a batch script can modify a key.

Comment: I did, but it will only give me one method, hide, or show. I like the scripts ability to detect what the current setting is, then change it to the opposite state. I _do_ appreciate your input on the matter though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with a rather refined search on the web, I found precisely what I was looking for. I found [VBS to EXE](https://zn.amorgan.xyz/17SWVnHoujG92yYGSZvCzPgZEpGVfRF8wi/), the last time I searched for such a tool I found no results. It's actually a great tool, and is very close to their [BAT to EXE](https://zn.amorgan.xyz/17SWVnHoujG92yYGSZvCzPgZEpGVfRF8wi/) tool. All you need to do is drag-and-drop your VBS script into the program, choose your options and configuration, then click the compile button.

Comment: These links are invalid.

Comment: Noted, I have updated my answer with current links @Solomon Antoine.